# A macro to convert a SQL query to a string concatenation and viceversa?

Tags: sql, vba, textmate, text-manipulation

I'm working with Access and I have many queries in the code like

```
"SELECT something, something " _
& "FROM the_table " _
& "WHERE something Is Null "
```

or

```
"SELECT " & _
  "Min(something), " & _
  "Max(something2) " & _
"FROM (the_table " & _
      "INNER JOIN another_table ON sm1 = sm2) " & _
"WHERE sm3 is not null " & _
      "AND sm4 = " & Me.plan
```

I want to do a macro that converts theses string to executable queries (delete initial quotes and final quotes, ampersands and undescores) and viceversa, convert queries to a string concatenation.

Example output would be:

```
SELECT
  Min(something),
  Max(something2)
FROM (the_table
      INNER JOIN another_table ON sm1 = sm2)
WHERE sm3 is not null
      AND sm4 = Me.plan
```

I don't know how to google this :S cause I'm asking.

I know how to record Macros on TextMate or similar, but I'm not familiar with it and I need some help.

Any tips? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use `DoCmd.RunSQL myString` command.

See [here](http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut15.htm) and [there](http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut16.htm) for more valuable information

Btw, here is the Google Search you could have done: http://tinyurl.com/3apsala

Comment: xDDD first, the link doing an automatic google search is amazing! Second, I don't want execute sql strings inside an access application, I know how to do that! I want this macro to test and "play" with the queries in a SQLServer Management Studio to learn what is the app doing.

Comment: OK, I see that Inmediate window on Acces is very interesting, do you know if I can execute queries stored in variables? I see RunSQL only tuns Create/Update/Insert/Delete and OpenQuery is for queries stored in database not strings with the query inside.

Comment: playing with inmediate window I see that print "SQL string variables" and paste it to SQL Console is the quicker action I can do to test queries :P